# Using a good non-default font

Tags: fonts

A while back, I read large portions of the KOMA book and it in the authors talk about how most people can't recognize typography or type-setting in general. People shouldn't be allowed to change margins, line-spacing, fonts, etc.

Since I'm not comfortable making this decision myself, would you be able to recommend some good, Latex-compatible, preferably free fonts?

Nice ligatures and old style numbers are a plus (&, ff, fl, fi).

Also note, I only ever output my Latex files to PDF via `xelatex`.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a general purpose font for writing prose---mostly letters, reports, books and articles. I'm looking for a font that could just as easily have been made the default. I'm looking for suggestions that wouldn't outrage your if they were made the default in Latex from now on. It should be a Serif font. Something like Georgia, Baskerville, Palatino, etc. But with all the Latex niceties.

Comment: Asking the question "name a good (free) font" is about as productive as "name a good car" or "name a fine camera". Without knowing the purpose of your typesetting ambitions, it's simply not possible to provide a decent answer. Please consider augmenting your question to tell us more about the subject matter (schololarly articles?, poetry?, shock advertising?, wedding invitations?), the presence of any mathematics in your publications, the need for non-Latin characters (arabic? hebrew? thai? chinese? korean? etc.), and anything else you think may be relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by “Latex niceties”?

Comment: @morbusg Proper quotes (which palatino doesn't have), fi, fl, Qu, kerning

Comment: Those all depend on the font and have nothing to do with (La)TeX. Palatino quotes are a matter of taste.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fonts outside of LaTeX distributions. All fonts can be used with ``xelatex``, so the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with LaTeX.

Comment: It's a difficult question that depends on the kind of document. For example, most people would argue you need a seriffed typeface for the main body of a book's text. Likewise, a sans serif is a better option for a flier. I suggest reading a good introduction to typography. Bringhurst's [_Elements of Typographic Style_](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Typographic-Style-Robert-Bringhurst/dp/0881791326) is an excellent introduction.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Even among "general purpose fonts", there is such a large range of styles and characteristics to choose from -- plus, there are personal tastes and preferences to take into account (and one can't argue about tastes, right?!) -- that it's not possible to come up with a short list of fonts that will please everyone.

That said, I believe there's widespread agreement that the serif fonts cut in the late fifteenth century and throughout the 16th century (usually labelled "old-style" or "garalde" -- a contraction of "Garamont" and "Aldus") do exceptionally well in terms of readability. Many font families that have been designed over the past few decades consciously or unconsciously copy most of the characteristics of the garaldes. Hence, you may seriously want to consider fonts such as [Palatino](http://www.linotype.com/de/1317/Palatino-family.html) (by Zapf), [Dante](http://www.linotype.com/de/1687/Dante-family.html) (Mardersteig), [Sabon](http://www.linotype.com/de/1150401/Sabor-family.html) (Tschichold), and any number of `Garamond` look-alikes that are on the market. Note that the original `Palatino`, `Dante`, and `Sabon` font families are *not* free of charge. However, free clones of `Palatino` do exist -- including several for easy use under pdfLaTeX (cf the `mathpazo`, `tgpagella`, and `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages).

A personal-favorite font that is general purpose, available free of charge, and feature-rich is [Cardo](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html). It is distributed in Opentype format and comes with bold and italic variants (but no bold-italic). In overall style, `Cardo` is quite close to the `Bembo` font. The latter font is based on a font used by Aldus to publish a tract written by a Cardinal Bembo in the 1490s and is considered one of the the premier "old-style" fonts.

Comment: How do you get Cardo font files?

Comment: @Costi: You could click on the hyperlink in "Cardo" in the first sentence of the paragraph above; in the new page, click on the "this file" link to download the zip file containing the font-related files. Extract the font files. Just how they need to be activated depends on your computer's OS.

Comment: @Mico: thank you. I have been using \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}, and I would like to change the font of the whole document into cardo. If I just type \usepackage[cardo]{mathdesign}, the font I get is not cardo.

Comment: @costi: please consider posting a new question, in which you describe your TeX setup -- which OS, which TeX distribution? That way, more people will see your question and have a chance to provide answers.

Answer (score 23):

There's really not many to choose from when restricted to free fonts, at least not when requiring italic, bold, bold italic, small caps, text figures, multiple optical sizes, good kerning, etc. That list diminishes even further when the need for maths is thrown into the mix.

That said, these are the ones I've found and used:

- [TeX Gyre fonts collection](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) (GUST/URW++): Pagella for Palatino look-alike, Termes for Times look-alike, Schola for Century Schoolbook look-alike (this is among my personal favourites!), and others. These include many of the requirements listed above.
- Adobe Minion Pro and Myriad Pro which come with Adobe Acrobat Reader.
- And when maths is a requirement, there is exactly one OpenType Unicode choice: [STIX](http://www.stixfonts.org/)/[XITS](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math) which includes everything. For an OpenType math font to be used together with other font, there are: [Asana Math](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/Asana-Math/) for Palatino-look, and [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) for a hand-drawn -look.
- For Greek, the Greek Font Society has [many freely available faces](http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/en_typefaces1.html).

So, my hat off to all those people who work on fonts. To our very own @[Khaled Hosny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729/khaled-hosny) especially; Thank you! `:-)`

Comment: I’d like to upvote the last paragraph separate a second time!

Comment: About Minion and Myriad: "these free versions lack some of the requirements listed above" makes no sense. "Nice ligatures and old style numbers are a plus (&, ff, fl, fi)." -- small caps (I guess Myriad Pro doesn't have them anyway), historical ligatures, bold+italic+regular+bolditalic you've got everything there -- the only thing missing from those Adobe Reader free fonts is a bunch of optical sizes (which most fonts don't have anyway), condensed forms etc.

Comment: @Joseph: You're right, thanks. This is a somewhat old answer and I don't recall what made me write that (I believe I thought it lacked "old style" figures and small caps, which I just tested are included).

Comment: Some years have passed now, and perhaps it should be mentioned that there are now Math fonts available for the TeX Gyre fonts mentioned in this answer. Also, STIX Two also deserves mention. Much improved over its predecessors!

Answer (score 9):

There ist this resource for LaTeX: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

But I recommend to consider [Linux Libertine](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=1&L=1)

Answer (score 4):

The Question is off-topic but anyway here are 2 resources:

[Top 10 Typefaces used by book design winners](http://fontfeed.com/archives/top-ten-typefaces-used-by-book-design-winners/)

[100 Best of Fonts](http://www.100besteschriften.de/)

Comment: Why do you think it's off-topic?

Comment: Because there _is_ no good, unique, technical answer -- to a great extent, it's a matter of taste. So, sorry, this isn't really the place for it (although we all love beautiful typesetting!).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. There is an element of technicality, though. Does the font do proper kerning? Does it include ligatures? Does it do old numbers?

Comment: There is an English version of [100 Best of Fonts](http://100besttypefaces.com)