# How can I use another non-esoteric font/font style in equations?

Tags: fonts

Usually when we write equations, we tend to use:

- Italicized roman font, for symbols: `$a, b, c$`.
- Non-italicized roman font, for text `$a_\text{in}, \mathrm{hello}$`
- Boldface symbols for, well, emphasis (sometimes also for matrices or vectors: `$\mathbf{P} \subseteq \mathbf{NP}$`
- Sans-serif text `$\mathsf{}$`
- Calligraphic `$\mathcal{}`$
- Small-caps `$\mathsf{}`$
- Fixed-width/monospace `$\mathtt{}`$

So, in this paper I'm writing, regular text is taken up by, well, the text of the paper; I don't want to use boldface since I'm not emphasizing, and there are two kinds of constructs for which I use sans-serif and small-caps respectively. I also use $\texttt$ for typesetting fragments of computer program code (and these sometimes go in equations/formulas).

Since $\mathcal$ and $\mathfrak$ are good mostly for single-letter symbols rather than for complete words, I find myself in need of another style.

I want to be able to write `The quick brown fox jumped over $\magichere{dogs} \cap \magichere{lazy}$` and for "dogs" to be "text-ish", but not look like a continuation of the sentence. `\magichere` is what I'm missing of course.

I've been wondering - is there some other font style, or even a different font, I could use for a third kind of constructs in my paper? Perhaps another roman fonts which is different than the paper body, on one hand, but does not seem out-of-place on the other?

Comment: hard to say (and design is more or less off topic) . `\mathtt` is one possibility or you could choose a script font more designed for complete words any handwriting font for example or `\mathfrak`  or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is there nothing like an "alternative roman" or "second roman"? Perhaps something baseed on one of [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53428/5640)?

Comment: sure there are thousands of roman fonts and you can use pretty much any of them, but I didn't suggest it as I don't think your readers would like having to squint at individual words to see if they are in computer modern or times or palatino or ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See edit for a clearer motivation

Comment: as I say I'd use \texttt rather than a differently styled roman.

Comment: Aside: `\mathsf` definitely doesn't produce small-caps; instead, it produces math-mode sans-serif output.

Comment: (off-topic) where you specify non-italicized roman font, you've got the usages of `\text` and `\mathrm` reversed.  "hello" is logically `\text`, and `\mathrm' should be used for things like subscript indicators that aren't variables.

Comment: Are you open to using LuaLaTeX? The reason I ask is that LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package let you specify more than one math alphabet at a time. E.g., you could use the "Euler fonts" as an extra math alphabet.

Comment: the computer modern family has a "slanted" style that can be used with `\textsl`.  in this style, the letters have a roman shape (see the difference particularly in letters like "a" and "g") but are inclined to an angle of (i think) 15 degrees.  some other font families have a style sometimes called "oblique" that is equivalent.

Comment: A more serious thought than my answer, what about using a font with a variety of weights? Use a light font weight maybe?

Answer (score 2):

if you are willing to use computer modern fonts, there is a slanted alternative,
accessed with `\textsl`.   in this style, the letters have a roman shape (see the
difference particularly in letters like "a" and "g") but are inclined to an angle
of (i think) 15 degrees. some other font families have a style sometimes called
"oblique" that is equivalent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumped over the \textsl{lazy} dog.

\textsl{The quick brown fox jumped over the \textit{lazy} dog.}

\textit{The quick brown fox jumped over the \textsl{lazy} dog.}

$ The quick brown fox jumped over the \textsl{ lazy } dog. $
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

by the way, the italic form used for single-letter variables in computer modern is
quite different from the text italic -- it is wider, and letters do not kern as they do in text.  also observe that explicit spaces were needed (in the `\textsl`
example within the math string) to avoid everything being run together.

also note (though not shown here) that `\mathit` is *not* the same as "math
italic" (as used for variables).  `\mathit` is actually the text italic shape,
and supports spaces as any other text font; the name is knuth's assignment,
based on the fact that it can be used *only* in math environments.

Answer (score 0):

`\magichere`... Sorry about this. And I'm only a beginner at producing pixie dust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.shapes}
\newcommand\magicpixiedust[1]{%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(word.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt]  (word) {#1};
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
      \node[draw=black!30,fill=yellow,ellipse,decorate,
          decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star,shape size=1mm}
        ] at (word) {\phantom{\tiny #1}};
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumped over $\magicpixiedust{dogs} \cap \magicpixiedust{lazy}$
\end{document}
```

[image]